# jOOQ: How to Create Timestamps in a Custom Time Zone (as with JDBC)?

Tags: mysql, datetime, jdbc, jooq

### Short Version

In a MySQL DB I have a column with the data type `DATETIME`. With JDBC such values can be set to [**timestamps in a certain timezone**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setTimestamp%28int,%20java.sql.Timestamp,%20java.util.Calendar%29). Can this be done with [jOOQ](http://www.jooq.org/), too?

### Longer Version

I have a sample table with this schema:

```mysql
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `my_test_db` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin ;
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `my_test_db`.`my_table` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `my_time` DATETIME NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) )
```

I’m specifically interested in `DATETIME` columns, *not* in `TIMESTAMP` columns. I only ever want to work with UTC timestamps – no matter from where I query the data and from where I get timestamps to insert into the DB.

With JDBC I can solve the problem as in this sample application:

```java
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.TimeZone;

public class MyTest {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection conn = null;
    try {
      conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/my_test_db?"
        + "useTimezone=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC");

      PreparedStatement prepStmt = conn.prepareStatement(
         "INSERT INTO `my_test_db`.`my_table` (`my_time`) VALUES (?)");

      // NB: this particular timestamp is just an example; I actually get
      // timestamps from elsewhere but I can be certain that they’re in UTC.
      Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));

      // This is the interesting line which I’d like to port to jOOQ; I can pass
      // in an additional “Calendar” object from which time zone information is
      // taken into account for the new “DATETIME” value:
      prepStmt.setTimestamp(1, new Timestamp(cal.getTimeInMillis()), cal);
      prepStmt.executeUpdate();
    } finally {
      if (conn != null) {
        conn.close();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In jOOQ I seemingly can’t specify the time zone information:

```java
// …
DSLContext dslContext = DSL.using(conn);
dslContext.insertInto(MY_TABLE)
  .set(MY_TABLE.MY_TIME, new Timestamp(cal.getTimeInMillis()))
  .execute();
```

Consequently, any timestamps created with the above jOOQ code are in the system default time zone. Can I change that?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it using a new class returning a jOOQ field implementing the utc_timestamp() function.

```
package org.jooq.impl;

import ...

public class Custom_MySQL_UTCTimestamp extends AbstractFunction<Timestamp> {

    public Custom_MySQL_UTCTimestamp() {
        super("utc_timestamp", SQLDataType.TIMESTAMP);
    }

    @Override
    final Field<Timestamp> getFunction0(Configuration configuration) {
        if(configuration.family() == SQLDialect.MYSQL){
            return function("utc_timestamp", SQLDataType.TIMESTAMP);            
        }
        return function("current_timestamp", SQLDataType.TIMESTAMP);    
    }
}
```

Notice that you have to keep the package name org.jooq.impl.

Then in my code I use it like this:

```
InsertSetMoreStep<TableRecord> insert = db.insertInto(TABLE)
    .set(TABLE.DATE,new Custom_MySQL_UTCTimestamp())
```

TABLE.DATE is of MySQL type DATETIME

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, I believe that relying on internal, package private classes (`org.jooq.impl.AbstractFunction<T>` in this case) is bad practice and not a maintainable solution. These classes can change at any time, even in bugfix releases.

Comment: Well, as a general principle I definitely agree. How did you solve it yourself?

Comment: I change the default time zone when my program starts up: `TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));`  This is also a bit kludgy and may not work for others. However, I’m in the convenient situation that the change _is_ possible in my program without breaking anything.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in the following way:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Madrid"));
long currentTime = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
```

and then to get it into your table using JOOQ:

```
dslContext.insertInto(MY_TABLE)
  .set(MY_TABLE.MY_TIME, new Timestamp(currentTime))
  .execute();
```

EDIT: The above will only save the UTC time as Chriki mentioned in the comment below.

However, this might work:

```
long currentTime = calendar.getTimeInMillis() + TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New_York").getOffset(Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis())
```

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/timezone_getoffset_date.htm
Basically, finding the offset from UTC and then adding it to current UTC time.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I don’t think this will make any difference. Actually it’s effectively the same code I have posted in my question. Note that [`calendar.getTimeInMillis()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#getTimeInMillis()) will always return a UTC timestamp, no matter which `calendar` is used.